# Аутентификация и IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Здравствуйте. У меня возник такой вопрос. При попытке запустить веб-приложение ASP.NET MVC 4 из под отладчика я получаю ошибку "401.2.: Нет прав доступа: Вход не выполнен из-за настройки сервера"

В web.config стоит в разделе <system.web> есть секция

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

При попытке добавить следующий раздел:

```
<system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
```

Получаю ошибку 500.19  "К запрошенной странице нет доступа, так как данные конфигурации, связанные с этой страницей являются недопустимыми."

Веб-сервер IIS Express 8.0
Может кто-то знает как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

В web.config

```
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

Замените на

```
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
```